# What is the GEGL function in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

What is the GEGL function in Gimp?

Comment: Off topic - it's about the inner workings of a particular piece of software and has no connection with graphic design.

Comment: You mean the processing engine or the very visible experimental "GEGL operation" tool that has quite a few artistic things such as c2g filter? :)

Comment: The visible tool.

Comment: In the current 2.9.x development cycle, which will be released as 2.10.x, something being available in the GEGL tool means that it hasn't been put into the menu structure elsewhere yet. GIMP 2.10 is supposed to look almost exactly like GIMP 2.8, but with almost everything being done by GEGL ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GEGL](http://www.gegl.org/) is a graphics manipulation library which gimp is using for some functions. It's graph based, that means basically that it supports non destructive image manipulation. From what I know, the integration of GEGL into Gimp is still an ongoing process.